# Deno / Postgres "invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate" error

Tags: postgresql, deno, supabase, tls1.3, deno-deploy

I'm using `deno` db to connect to a supabase postgres server.

Here's the error from deno deploy.

> TLS connection failed with message: invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate: UnsupportedCertVersion
> Defaulting to non-encrypted connection

[image]

Establishing connection here:

```
import { Database, PostgresConnector } from "https://deno.land/x/denodb/mod.ts";
import "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/load.ts";

export const connection = (() => {
  const DENODB_PGURL = Deno.env.get('DENODB_PGURL');

  if (DENODB_PGURL) {
    return new PostgresConnector({uri: DENODB_PGURL});  
  }

  const DENODB_HOST = Deno.env.get('DENODB_HOST');
  if (!DENODB_HOST) throw new Error('DENODB_HOST is not set');
  const DENODB_USERNAME = Deno.env.get('DENODB_USERNAME');
  if (!DENODB_USERNAME) throw new Error('DENODB_USERNAME is not set');
  const DENODB_PASSWORD = Deno.env.get('DENODB_HOST');
  if (!DENODB_PASSWORD) throw new Error('DENODB_PASSWORD is not set');
  const DENODB_DATABASE = Deno.env.get('DENODB_DATABASE');
  if (!DENODB_DATABASE) throw new Error('DENODB_DATABASE is not set');
  
  return new PostgresConnector({
    host: DENODB_HOST,
    username: DENODB_USERNAME,
    password: DENODB_PASSWORD,
    database: DENODB_DATABASE,
  });

})()

const db = new Database(connection);

export default db;
```

I'm issuing a `.create` call later in the code.

To be clear the connection works and records are being created

Comment: That looks like the error from the client side.  Look in the db server's log fie to see how it experiences this error.  Also, what version of the database is this?

Comment: Maybe you have already tried this, but have you tried updating your Supabase CLI to the most recent version?

Comment: @dshukertjr this is happening on deno deploy not using the subpabase cli :)

Comment: Not sure, but might be related to this Deno issue: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13350

Comment: Can you share an [mcve] of a function that is failing?

Answer (score 0):

through this doc: https://deno.com/blog/v1.13

you can try `deno run --unsafely-ignore-certificate-errors ...`

[image]